# How to put mutiple links in one line

Tags: html

I want to display 7-9 html links in one line, but whenever I add another link, the last link goes down and forms another row. I want to put them in one line.
like

```
<link1> <link2><link3><link4><link5><link6><link7> 

<li><a href="adminpanel.jsp">HOME</a>
                        <li><a href="Checkin.jsp">Check In</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Check Out</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Re-Issue</a></li>
                        <li><!--movies er drop down-->
                            <a href="#">Student<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Approve</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Fine</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Check List</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Department</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">Faculty<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Books issued</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li> <a href="#">SEARCH<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Student</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                            </ul>
```

Comment: Show an example of what you've tried and how you hoped it would look.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: @RickHitchcock where should i put it?

Comment: By "links," I assumed you were referring to `a` tags, but now that you've posted your HTML, I see they are within `li` tags.  Do you want only the sub-menus to be on one line?

Comment: no the main menus  
the  SEARCH link always goes down @RickHitchcock

Answer (score 1):

Use these styles:

```
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ucsbuw8/)

Answer (score -1):

In the list that you put them in make a class and then in css add to the class: display:inline;
example: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaHurlburt/34nzt2d1/

```
<ul class="links">
    <a href="google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="google.com">Google1</a>
    <a href="google.com">Google2</a>
    <a href="google.com">Google3</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not valid html, because an ul tag may only contain li tags

Comment: Not only that: the links will also wrap into another row when there are too many of them.

Comment: @josh H your method worked though the drop down list disappeared